# spread() is producing NA values.(R programming)

Tags: r, tidyverse, spread

I am downloading data from census.gov using R library tidycensus data. then i am transforming data using 
 spread(). Each geoid has many columns with estimate value, but it is producing NA for rest of the columns.

[actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoipD.png)

[data after applying spread function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx0uJ.png)

Please help me to correct the data.

Dput:

```
structure(list(GEOID = c(13001950100, 13001950100, 13001950100, 
13001950100, 13001950100, 13001950100), NAME = c("Census Tract 9501, Appling County, Georgia", 
"Census Tract 9501, Appling County, Georgia", "Census Tract 9501, Appling County, Georgia", 
"Census Tract 9501, Appling County, Georgia", "Census Tract 9501, Appling County, Georgia", 
"Census Tract 9501, Appling County, Georgia"), variable = c("S2401_C01_001", 
"S2401_C01_002", "S2401_C01_003", "S2401_C01_004", "S2401_C01_005", 
"S2401_C01_006"), estimate = c(1406, 271, 54, 54, 0, 0), moe = c(214, 
87, 43, 43, 13, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you post your data as code rather than an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each ID to be in one row:

```
library(tidyverse)     
df <- df %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = c("estimate", "moe"))
```

Comment: Awesome. If this solved your question, feel free to click on the checkmark on the left to show that it's accepted.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), GEOID + NAME ~ variable, value.var = c("estimate", "moe"))
```